# ElasticSearch query string Query default_operator

Tags: elasticsearch

The following query finds all the documents that have all of the words "look", "for" and "this:

```
"query": {
            "query_string": {
                "query": "look for this",
                "default_operator":"AND"
          }
        }
```

While this one finds any documents that have any of those three words:

```
"query": {
            "query_string": {
                "query": "look for this",
                "default_operator":"OR"
          }
        }
```

My question is how to change the query so that it performs a Google style search, i.e. it first lists all the documents that have all of the terms then documents that have any of them?

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch by default will give higher score to documents where all the terms are present. You could use [explain api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html) to see that.

If you really want to give documents very high score where all the terms are present, then you could use [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "default_field": "title",
            "query": "look for this",
            "default_operator": "AND"
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "default_field": "title",
            "query": "look for this"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT 1**

You could use [fuction score query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) to give high boost to desired results. Try following query

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "query_string": {
                "fields": [
                  "title"
                ],
                "query": "look for this",
                "default_operator": "AND"
              }
            },
            {
              "query_string": {
                "query": "look for this",
                "fields": [
                  "title"
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "filter": {
            "query": {
              "query_string": {
                "fields": [
                  "title"
                ],
                "query": "look for this",
                "default_operator": "AND"
              }
            }
          },
          "weight": 10
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it is not bringing the documents with all words on the top. How can I make that happen?

Comment: I have added one more approach, You could try changing weight to 100 if you still dont get desired results. I am still not sure why would ES wont give high score to documents with all terms present, which version of ES you are using? you are also queyring on '_all' field but I dont see how that could be an issue